# Setup GoDaddy SSL in Amazon ec2

Tags: linux, apache, ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Apache Version  Apache/2.4.12 (Amazon) OpenSSL/1.0.1k-fips PHP/5.6.8

I have Elastic IP Amazon ec2-user Linux, Free tier.

I have Godaddy SSL.

I have Godaddy Domain (kenn.com) Pointing to Amazon Route 53 Host Zone

I tried to open the website it works perfectly. No issues in pointing.

---

I already have this files:

I run this command: `openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout kenn.com.key -out kenn.csr`

Generating this files: `kenn.com.key` `kenn.csr`

I downloaded SSL files from Godaddy generated from kenn.csr: `4262b7fc267ecb1b.crt` `gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt`

---

> OpenSSL support is    enabled

I Tried running: `sudo yum install mod_ssl`

Error:

```
[root@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx my-ssl-certifications]# sudo yum install mod_ssl
Error: httpd24 conflicts with httpd-2.2.29-1.5.amzn1.x86_64
Error: mod24_ssl conflicts with 1:mod_ssl-2.2.29-1.5.amzn1.x86_64
Error: httpd24-tools conflicts with httpd-tools-2.2.29-1.5.amzn1.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

- I dont know how to check if mod_ssl is working

---

> a.) SSLCertificateFile /home/ec2-user/site.com.crt
>
> b.) SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/ec2-user/site.key
>
> c.) SSLCACertificateFile /home/ec2-user/gd_bundle.crt

- I dont know how to edit this `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf`

it has to point to my files right? where can i get `site.com.crt`?

b. is `kenn.com.key`

c. is `gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt`

a. is what????????

still have two files `4262b7fc267ecb1b.crt` `kenn.csr` what are they used for?

REFERENCE: http://jafty.com/blog/installing-godaddy-ssl-certificate-on-amazon-ec2/

UPDATE:
i run : `sudo service httpd restart`

```
[root@ip-172-31-41-181 ec2-user]# sudo service httpd restart
Stopping httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting httpd: [Tue May 26 01:32:17.041564 2015] [alias:warn] [pid 11944] AH00671: The Alias directive in /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf at line 15 will probably never match because it overlaps an earlier Alias.
[Tue May 26 01:32:17.041673 2015] [alias:warn] [pid 11944] AH00671: The Alias directive in /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf at line 16 will probably never match because it overlaps an earlier Alias.
                                                           [  OK  ]
```

but when i visit https://ken.com

it says `This webpage is not available`

Comment: It is really hard to answer without knowing the format of your key and how your instance is configured

Comment: @scrowler i followed this: http://jafty.com/blog/installing-godaddy-ssl-certificate-on-amazon-ec2/

Comment: Sounds like mod ssl might be installed already, you may have misunderstood that step. Type sudo httpd -t to test your syntax and httpd start to see if it will start with your current configuration.

Comment: @scrowler UPDATE:
i run : `sudo service httpd restart`, result in updated question-

Comment: having the same problem, up for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Amazon.

Then EC2.

Click Security Groups.

Add an HTTPS method.

Comment: Thats what it was missing, thanks! its working now :D